# Hangman in javascript, when letter is wrong retuns always true

Tags: javascript

I have a game hangman. But I tried to make the logic, that if a user enters the wrong letter, then the user will get a message that he/she has to try again.

But now even if the user has chosen the correct letter, the user will get the message that he/she has to try it again.

This is the code:

```
<script>
  var words = [
    "ha",
    "pe",
    "jaa"
  ];

  var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var answareArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answareArray[i] = "_";
  }
  var remainingLetters = word.length;

  while (remainingLetters > 0) {
    //gaming code
    alert(answareArray.join(" "));
    //Get a gues from the user:
    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click cancel to stop");
    if (guess === null) {
      break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
      alert("Please enter a single letter");
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {

        if (word[j] !== guess) {
          debugger;
          alert("try again");
        }

        if (word[j] === guess) {
          if (answareArray[j] !== "_") {
            alert("Letter already be guessed");
            break;
          } else {
            answareArray[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  alert(answareArray.join(" "));
  alert("Good Job the answare was: " + word);
</script>
```

And in this part:

```
if (word[j] !== guess) {
  debugger;
  alert("try again");
}
```

I try to return the message to the user.

So what do I have to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show the alert after you checked all the letters, you're currently showing it at each iteration.

You can do that by using a flag (a boolean variable).

Here is an example:

```
var goodGuess = false;
for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    if (word[j] === guess) {

        goodGuess = true;

        if (answareArray[j] !== "_") {
            alert("Letter already be guessed");
            break;
        } else {

            answareArray[j] = guess;
            remainingLetters--;
        }
    }
}

if(!goodGuess){
    alert("try again");
}
```

What this does, is to first set the `goodGuess` variable to `false`, then go through all the letters and if the user's guess is equal to any of them, set `goodGuess` to `true`.

At the end of the loop (after all the letters were checked), if `goodGuess` is `false`, the alert is shown.